# htaccess url rewrite: example.com/admin/.php > example.com/admin/index

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this this mod rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But wen i go to the page: http://www.example.nl/admin/ 
it must redirect me to http://www.example.nl/admin/index
instead i get an 404 errorpage (The requested URL /admin/.php was not found on this server.)

How i can redirect my submap to the index page?

should i use this code for all my submaps? :

```
Redirect 301 /admin/ http://www.example.nl/admin/index
```

or are there better options to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#add these
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @user1167022 oh okay, but have optimised and added some trailing slash problem prevention. U can use the new code. Also, clear your browser's cache before using.